# WCF Service constructor injection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, simple-injector

I am trying to create a WCF Service which has 1 dependency resolved by constructor injection. Using the quickstart for WCF, a App_Start folder was created. In here the only thing I changed was adding

```
container.RegisterPerWcfOperation<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

If I understand correctly the web.config should be empty? The WCF Service will be hosted on IIS, and it has a virtual directory.

When I don't change anything, and run the service test from VS2012, it works, but when I try in IIS, nothing happens. I did see however that the service test is using basichttp_binding. Is there any way I can alter this with simple injector? I would like to create a rest wcf (webhttpbinding). Currently when I try to go to the page I get a 400 Bad Request as response.

Comment: Simple Injector cannot manage your IIS/WCF configuration and this question appears to be about WCF configuration. An empty web.config does not sound correct to me.

Comment: Then how should I set this up? Seeing as when I do specify a wcf service in the web.config, I get the error that I don't have a default non-parameter constructor. And when I add a default constructor it throws the error that I have 2 constructors

Comment: Can I suggest you look at the following documentation? it doesn't sound like you have configured the markup in svc file correctly. https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Integration

Comment: Hi @RoyTeeuwen, did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: yes @qujck I managed to get it working. I created interfaces for the WCF services and added these as contracts in the web.config. After this it seemed to work!